# FIFOQueue is closed and has insufficient elements

Tags: tensorflow, queue

I'm trying to run the [FaceNet tensorflow's implementation of David Sandberg](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet) with my own dataset (script train_tripletloss.py). At some point while training execution stops because of a:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError, FIFOQueue '_0_batch_join/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 9, current size 0)
```

The exception seems to be caused by batch_join operation. I've read somewhere that it could be causes by an empty queue. As I am a total beginner to Tensorflow, I don't know where to look and how to debug. Here is part of the code:

```
    input_queue = data_flow_ops.FIFOQueue(capacity=100000,
                                dtypes=[tf.string, tf.int64],
                                shapes=[(3,), (3,)],
                                shared_name=None, name=None,)
    enqueue_op = input_queue.enqueue_many([image_paths_placeholder, labels_placeholder])

    nrof_preprocess_threads = 4
    images_and_labels = []
    for _ in range(nrof_preprocess_threads):
        filenames, label = input_queue.dequeue()
        images = []
        for filename in tf.unstack(filenames):
            file_contents = tf.read_file(filename)
            image = tf.image.decode_image(file_contents, channels=3)

            ...
            image.set_shape((args.image_size, args.image_size, 3))
            images.append(tf.image.per_image_standardization(image))
        images_and_labels.append([images, label])


    image_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.batch_join(
        images_and_labels, batch_size=batch_size_placeholder, 
        shapes=[(args.image_size, args.image_size, 3), ()], 
        enqueue_many=True,
        capacity=4 * nrof_preprocess_threads * args.batch_size,
        allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
    image_batch = tf.identity(image_batch, 'image_batch')
    image_batch = tf.identity(image_batch, 'input')
    labels_batch = tf.identity(labels_batch, 'label_batch')
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: The usual cause of this exception is either (i) there is no more data to process, or (ii) a failure in some operation "upstream" of the `tf.train.batch_join()` occurred. For an example of the latter case, one of the `tf.read_file()` or `tf.image.decode_image()` operations might have failed on a bad filename or corrupt image. Check your output logs to see if other operations failed before the error message you shared in the question.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Reason of the failure was that MacOS has added this damned hidden file (.DS_Store) to my directory of images.